# Allow upload via the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app

Can we please allow upload of images (like screenshots) via the iOS app?

For my last question I had to use a random imgr app to upload my screenshot and copy the link to my question which was quite a hassle.

Comment: Interesting idea. I could see using skitch or another app to mark up / adjust the images if needed. This is already possible using the main site from a mobile - so perhaps explaining how to do that might suffice for the 1.0?